# CSS Media Queries for specific iPads

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to target specific iPads using CSS Media Queries
The three that I want to target are:

- iPad 9.7"  = 1024px x 768
- iPad Pro 10.5" = 1112px x 834px
- iPad Pro 12.9" = 1366px x 1024px

I only need to target landscape mode.

This is how I have set up my Media Queries:

```
//iPad 9.7"
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

//iPad 10.5"
@media screen and (min-width: 1112px) and (max-width: 1112px)   {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

//iPad 12.9"
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 1366px) { 
  body {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

Both the iPad 12.9 and 10.5 Media Queries work, but the 9.7 also has a red background.

[image]

If I change the Media Query for the iPad 9.7 to include `and (min-width: 1024px)` then it works, but the 10.5 Media Query stops working.

What is the correct way to achieve this? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated! TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the first media query then set the min-width just above the previous breakpoint -- see the code below

```css
body { height: 100vh; margin: 0 }

/* iPad 9.7 */
body { background-color: green }

/* iPad 10.5 */
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  body { background-color: red }
}

/* iPad 12.9 */
@media screen and (min-width: 1113px) { 
  body { background-color: orange }
}
```